# Perl : Why do double quotes add extra space when printing?

Tags: perl

I expect the following 2 prints are the same.

```
@a=(a..z);
print "@a\n";
print @a;
```

But actually, it gives me this:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Why the extra spaces?

I am using ActivePerl for Windows.

#### Update

With the following 2 answers, I came up with this:

```
use English;
$LIST_SEPARATOR="*";
@a=(a..z);
print "@a\n";
```

And it gave me this:

```
a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the default value for `$"` is a space and the default value for `$,` is an empty string.

You can read about all of Perl's special variables in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: While the `$"` is one of the variables at play here, Dave's answer is the only one that mentions `$,` which is also at work in the question. Good job Dave. +1

Answer (score 7):

See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$")

- `$LIST_SEPARATOR`
- `$"`

> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted
>   string or a similar context such as `/.../`, its elements are separated
>   by this value. Default is a space.

Answer (score 7):

This is documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Array-Interpolation):

> Arrays and slices are interpolated into double-quoted strings by
>   joining the elements with the delimiter specified in the [$"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%22) variable
>   ($LIST_SEPARATOR if "use [English](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html);" is specified), space by default.